# External HDD fails to mount "exit status 13: `$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0)"

Tags: mount, ntfs

When I plug in my external hard disk I get this error message:

```
Unable to access “1.0 TB Volume”

Error mounting `/dev/sdb1` at `/media/jonny/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007`: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/jonny/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007"` exited with non-zero exit status 13: `$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).`

Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run `chkdsk /f` on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the `/dev/mapper/` directory, (e.g.
`/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1`). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

What shall I do now?

Comment: Are you dual-booting with Windows or do you have access to a Windows computer into which you can plug the disk? In that case do it and perform a Checkdisk on the drive from Windows.

Comment: Its like there is a windows os on there external drive. There is a file call hibernate on the windows partition that usually cause this. Make sure you shutdown windows properly shutdown /g

Answer (score 1):

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, its probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

**In Windows**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C: